# aws Amazon S3 client credentials in pig user defined function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-pig, emr

I made a user defined function for my pig script to delete a folder.
But how do i get the credentials?

```
REGISTER s3://emr-custom-jars/custom.jar;
```

if i put register in my pig script it can access files on aws storage.
so my credentials must be available for pig.
can i access my credentials or AmazoneS3Client without uploading my accessKey and secretKey inside my jar?

```
    private AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    private AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);  

    @Override
    public void deleteObjectsInFolder(String bucketName, String folderPath) {
        for (S3ObjectSummary file : s3client.listObjects(bucketName, folderPath).getObjectSummaries()){           
            s3client.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to provide the access credentials without having to hard-code the values in the jar. [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#AmazonS3Client())

> ```
> public AmazonS3Client()
> ```
>
> Constructs a new client to invoke service methods on Amazon S3. A credentials provider chain will be used that
>   searches for credentials in this order:
>
> > - Environment Variables - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_KEY
> > - Java System Properties - aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey
> > - Credential profiles file at the default location (~/.aws/credentials) shared by all AWS SDKs and the AWS CLI
> > - Instance Profile Credentials - delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service